# React Native New Date string

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using react-native-calendar-picker. Initially when my app data loads, if there isn't a date stored that was picked, I assign the specific array with `new Date()` which returns something like this:  `Thu Feb 18 2016 22:58:12 GMT-0700 (MST)`. Once the user updates the date I store the new date in React Native's `AsyncStorage` which has a value something like this: `Mon Feb 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)`

However, once the app reloads the date value is returned like this: `"2016-02-29T07:00:00.000Z"`. The react-native-calendar-picker uses the date formatted like: `Mon Feb 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)`

Is there a way to get the date formatted back to this way?

Comment: Have you tried using moment.js?

Comment: @ChrisGeirman moment.js works only in debug mode(chrome environment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try,

```
String formatted = new Date("2016-02-29T07:00:00.000Z").toString();
```

Precisely be aware of data types,

`new Date()` would return a Date object. (2016-02-19T13:42:17.975Z)

`new Date().toString()` would return a formatted date string. (Fri Feb 19 2016 19:12:17 GMT+0530 (IST))